# ASP.NET Core Web api + WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, soap

I'm trying to get the employee I added via Get and I just get a blank sheet instead of what I expected. I just started studying recently and I don't quite understand why I did any wrong actions. Anyone with experience, please help
https://github.com/mistelltein/WebApplicationWithWCF
Here's my code, if anyone solved this problem before, i need your incructions

I rewrote the methods, reconnected to the WCF application, but nothing worked and still get a blank sheet when searching for an employee

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can use **Corewcf** in **ASP.NET Core**.

1.Add **Nuget** package:

**CoreWCF.HTTP**

2.Add code:

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices();
builder.Services.AddServiceModelMetadata();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior, UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();
app.UseServiceModel(serviceBuilder =>
{
    serviceBuilder.AddService<Service>();
    serviceBuilder.AddServiceEndpoint<Service, IService>(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), "/Service.svc");
    var serviceMetadataBehavior = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
});
```

IService.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
 public interface IService
 {
     [OperationContract]
     string GetData(int value);

     [OperationContract]
     CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
 }

 public class Service : IService
 {
     public string GetData(int value)
     {
         return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
     }

     public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
     {
         if (composite == null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
         }
         if (composite.BoolValue)
         {
             composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
         }
         return composite;
     }
 }

 // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
 [DataContract]
 public class CompositeType
 {
     bool boolValue = true;
     string stringValue = "Hello ";

     [DataMember]
     public bool BoolValue
     {
         get { return boolValue; }
         set { boolValue = value; }
     }

     [DataMember]
     public string StringValue
     {
         get { return stringValue; }
         set { stringValue = value; }
     }
 }
```